# How to setup a database connection on Amazon EC2 RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, prestashop, amazon-rds

I am Installing [Qloapps](https://qloapps.com/) on Amazon EC2 server and while installing the script, I am unable to configure database connection:

[image: configuration]

Also, I installed PHPMyAdmin on my server but I am unable to access with username and password.

Note: I am a Codesigner not Codeveloper

Comment: Make sure your RDS is accessible by the EC2. Check Security groups and subnet placements in VPC for RDS and EC2 instance.

Comment: How to make accessible by the EC2